# Emoji in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, emoji

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and installed it recently and I want to type Emoji and custom symbols but nothing happens when I press  `ctrl + .` and also I tried left clicking on search bar but there is no insert option I can only see copy,paste,etc. So do I have to install it first?

Comment: Unfortunately we don’t see the "Insert Emoji" option in the context menus of non-GTK apps, like Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, or LibreOffice, nor the ability to use the keyboard shortcuts. It's quite frustrating at times ... 

Comment: So I found an idea that we can only use emoji on only some places so is there a 
 terminal command to open it and then assign a keyboard shortcut to it? @Matigo

Answer (score 1):

On Kubuntu when I press <kbd>meta</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> a window opens with emojis I can select. Maybe this works on Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 1):

The support for emojis on Linux is not too consistent. The default `Ctrl+.` picker is only available in GNOME apps, and that only those linked with a recent-enough Gtk library.

For the most consistent experience, it's advised you install a standalone emoji keyboard app, such as [EF*CK chat keyboard](https://efck-chat-keyboard.github.io), and [assign a keybind for it](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) yourself. It's how I use it and couldn't be more pleased.

Comment: Works in gedit, faster than a rightclick! (`meta` + (typing) `gedit` then `ctrl+.`)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I checked a lot and it seems that Kubuntu and Chromium browsers dont support emoji like windows

but you can install emoji execution on your browser.

Comment: So how to install emoji execution on browser? @Am.Shekari

Comment: Go to the web store and find your own emoji extension on here

Comment: In new Kubuntu 20.4 LTS this problem is fixed in Vivaldi browser

Comment: Is that browser trust worthy like Chrome @Am.Shekari

Comment: Yes, it's use chromium and it's has very good options but its have a little problom's to but I do not think that these problems will prevent you from using it